Can cape be disabled on a mode basis?
I love using cape in text mode, but I cannot figure out how to stop it from activating in programming modes. Is it possible to either only enable it in certain modes or to disable it in specific modes?
I tried
(use-package cape)

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()
                (setq completion-at-point-functions
                  (list (cape-capf-super #'cape-dabbrev #'cape-dict)))))

but cape still activates, even in Fundamental mode.

You were almost right. Replace setq with setq-local and the variable that you are manipulating will only be set in text-mode and its descendents, rather than globally. That is the only thing you missed.
